# 404 This page could not be found. NextJS configuration and page routing problem?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, eslint, config, next.js13

When I npm run dev my page.jsx file isn't being taken as the root file and I'm consequently given the error: 404
This page could not be found. - in the style of a nextJS template setup. and this in the terminal: > next dev

▲ Next.js 13.5.4

- Local:        http://localhost:3000

✓ Ready in 2.4s
✓ Compiled /not-found in 2.2s (2607 modules)

[here is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLj2Q.png)

page.jsx

```
import HomePage from './pages/index';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <HomePage />
    </>
  );
}
```

layout.jsx

```
'use client';
import './globals.css';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Head from 'next/head';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import HeroSection from '../components/HeroSection';

function HomePage() {
  return (
    <Box>
      <HeroSection />
    </Box>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  parser: '@next/next', // Specifies the ESLint parser
  extends: ['next', 'prettier'],
  parserOptions: {
    project: './jsconfig.json',
  },
  plugins: [
    '@next/next',
    'next/core-web-vitals',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
};
```

.prettierrc.json

```
{
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "semi": true,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "jsxSingleQuote": true,
  "plugins": ["prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"]
}
```

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "esau-motors",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "format": "prettier --check --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "format:fix": "prettier --write --ignore-path .gitignore ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^2.1.1",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.8.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.17",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.4",
    "next": "13.5.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.5.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prettier": "3.0.3",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.5.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3"
  }
}
```

jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "src"

  }
}
```

Also, in every jsx file I have a red error underline at the start of each import: Parsing error: Cannot find module 'next/babel'
Require stack:

- /Users/#/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js
- /Users/#/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/eslint-parser.js
- /Users/#/node_modules/eslint-config-next/parser.js
- /Users/#/#/node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/dist/eslintrc.cjseslint

Babel doesn't come included with a next setup I thought?

I've copying many other project setups and nothing seems to work. I think it has something to do with the eslint setup? I had this project working and was deep into it, pretty sure I installed something to do with eslint and the project crashed. So I started a fresh project hoping to copy and paste pages and components, I installed eslint and prettier and haven't been able to see anything since!

Comment: If you believe it's a ESLint problme then check your commit history to see what ESLint change you made and fix it.

Comment: Can you please provide the CodeSandbox link for the above issue?.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).